# modalpopupextender always shown and targetcontrolid is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater and it has a column of linkbuttons in it. I want to add those linkbuttons to `targetcontrolid` but it failed because they are in the **repeater**. So i create an additional invisible button like this :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFakePopUp" runat="server" Text="" visible="false" 
    onclick="btnFakePopUp_Click"/>
```

And in i tried to link the linkbutton to the invisible button in this code :

```
 protected void lbtnPosition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        btnFakePopUp_Click(sender, e);
    }

    protected void btnFakePopUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        popupJob.Show();
    }
```

And this is my `modalpopupextender` code (my prefix is asp: so dont get confuse) :

```
 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="popupJob" runat="server" PopupControlID="panelPopup" CancelControlID="popupClose" TargetControlID="btnFakePopUp"
    Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="panelPopup">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="panelPopup" runat="server" BackColor="#ebf0ff" Width="300px">
<div>
    test<br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnApply" runat="server" Text="Apply" />
    <input id="popupClose" type="button" value="Close" />
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

The problems are :
1. The `panelpopup` is always shown...(it should be hidden, and only be shown when the user click the link button)
2. Nothing happened when i tried to click the link button (the `panelpopup` should be shown)
Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a btnFakePopup invisible you could set the display:none with CSS

example:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnFakePopUp" runat="server" style="display: none"></asp:ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why, but setting `btnFakePopUp` visibility to `true` corrected the problem.  Now my `modalpopupextender` is running smoothly.